# Gazebo Garden plugin and nested models?

Tags: sensors, simulation, gazebo

I have a problem that I'm not able to solve with Gazebo Garden.

I wrote a System plugin that handles a stereo camera, I need a plugin to interface the simulator with our SDK.

Differently from Gazebo Classic in Gazebo there is not a Multi Camera sensor, so I must associate the plugin to a model containing the two sensors instead of associating it to a single sensor.

This works correctly, but I have not found a way to add multiple simulated stereo cameras to the same robot model because I do not know how to associate each plugin to the correct sensors pair.

In SDF I could create nested models and I guess this can solve my issue, but how can I achieve the same when describing the robot with URDF in ROS2?

I'm going crazy trying to find a working solution :(

Comment: Wasn't this question asked earlier?

Comment: Yes, but in the wrong place ;)